# Git clone multiples repositories it is possible?

Tags: git

I need clone multiples repositories at the same time, instead of cloning one of clone one at a time, wanted to simplify this process that can be in prompt or an script whit node.js, someone has a solution?

The best way was to create a script, example: clone:"repository 1... & repository 2...."

npm rum clone

Comment: I'm assuming you execute some script for your operating system? Like a Bash script for Linux, or Command Line script for Windows? You can run your commands in background, thus they'll be running in parallel, although limited by the bandwidth of your internet connection

Comment: E.g. in a Bash script you can add one command `git clone 1 &` and another command `git clone 2 &`, the ampersand & makes them run in background

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel

Comment: Of course it is *possible*. What have you tried and what problem are you experiencing with that?

Comment: the solution from Alexey Larionov helped me, but how can I specify the path?

Comment: `git clone <repo1> <path/to/dir> & git clone <repo2> <path/to/dir>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. To do this, create a new cmd file. Add the following lines to it:

```
start "" /d <folder> <git.exe> clone <repo1>
start "" /d <folder> <git.exe> clone <repo2>
```

Replace `<folder>` with your local drive path. The repository will be cloned into this folder.
Replace `<git.exe>` with the full path to the git.exe file in your environment.
Replace `<repo1>` with a ref to the first repository.
Replace `<repo2>` with a ref to the second repository.

For example:

```
start "" /d D:\Repositories\ D:\PROGRAMM\Git\bin\git.exe clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git
start "" /d D:\Repositories\ D:\PROGRAMM\Git\bin\git.exe clone https://github.com/project-jedi/jcl.git
```

Then you can execute this cmd file. This way you can clone multiple repositories at the same time.

Also you can use `&&`. For example:

```
start "" /d <folder> <git.exe> clone <repo1> && start "" /d <folder> <git.exe> clone <repo2>
```

Comment: i didn't understand exactly how to run the script. I already have a directorio created and already navigated to him by cmd

Comment: This solution is relevant for Windows. `start` is a standard command that allows you to open an application. I checked it works in my environment. The command starts multiple instances of git.exe. Each git instance clones some repository.

Comment: For example, you saved these commands in a file, say CloneMultiples.cmd. You just open CloneMultiples.cmd from the command line.